# Importing .dll-s

Tags: python, kivy

I have a Kivy-App, which has to connect to a physical device.
The code for connection and controlling the device is already written in .dll files.
So I would like to import some functions from the .dll file.

I managed to to import it in python. Here's the code for it:

mydll.py :

```
import clr

# import dll-s
try:
    clr.AddReference("CETAx10_x15")
    clr.AddReference("Converter")
    clr.AddReference("NLog")
    clr.AddReference("ValueDefine")
    clr.AddReference("Python.Runtime")
except:
    clr.AddReference("cls\\CETAx10_x15")
    clr.AddReference("cls\\Converter")
    clr.AddReference("cls\\NLog")
    clr.AddReference("cls\\ValueDefine")
    clr.AddReference("cls\\Python.Runtime")

import CETAx10_x15
import Converter
import NLog
import ValueDefine
import Python.Runtime
import System


def get_openports():

    temp = []
    output = []

    ports_reply = CETAx10_x15.CETA.get_ports(temp)

    for elem in ports_reply[1]:
        output.append(elem)

    return output

print(get_openports())
```

Running it will return ['COM3','COM4'] , So it does what it should.

My Kivy App runs flawless without importing this mydll.py file. 
Importing this mydll.py in my Kivy App will return the following error-message:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Mirk\CETACal\logs\kivy_17-03-01_150.txt
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 193 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.2.dev0, git-c6018cc, 20170222
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 20:20:57) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Mirk\CETACal\logs\kivy_17-03-01_151.txt
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.3.0 - Build 10.18.14.4432'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 3
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.30 - Build 10.18.14.4432'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [EZS-2G      ] The system parameters are: ['C:\\Mirk\\CETACal\\main.py']
['COM3', 'COM4']
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Mirk\CETACal\main.py", line 2708, in <module>
     EZS.run()
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 802, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "C:\Mirk\CETACal\main.py", line 1745, in build
     self.root = Builder.load_file(os.path.join(cls.config.kvPATH, 'root.kv'))
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 301, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 380, in load_string
     self._apply_rule(widget, parser.root, parser.root)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 500, in _apply_rule
     rule.canvas_before, rootrule)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 804, in _build_canvas
     Instruction = Factory.get('Instruction')
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\factory.py", line 139, in __getattr__
     module = __import__(name=item['module'], fromlist='.')
 TypeError: __import__() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

As you see the ['COM3', 'COM4'] is printed out.

Both my app and "mydll.py" works like a charm.
But after importing it will fail.

I just do not understand why does two independently working program fail after the import.

I'm using:
Win7
python 3.4
Kivy 1.9.2.devs0 (released: 22.02)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it. I added the following line:

from importlib import **import**

to the file:

C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\kivy\factory.py